# disable/modify optimization flag for a single function in cmake

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, clang

I would like to disable compiler optimization for a **particular function** in a file with **cmake**.

I am aware of :

- `set_source_files_properties(filename.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_OPTIONS "-O0")`  in cmake to modify compiler options for an **entire file** in cmake

  or
- use `__attribute__((optnone)` for a function in the **source code** to disable optimization.

However I am looking for a solution **in cmake** that would disable/modify compiler optimization for a **particular function** in a file.

Comment: CMake "knows" nothing about your functions %)

Comment: You could add the appropriate pragmas or attributes in your source code wrapped with preprocessor directives and then define that symbol in cmake to activate them.

Comment: The real question is why? I suspect [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Just put problematic function in separate source file and now you know how to do it.

Comment: @MarekR nice suggestion, but might not always be an easy option (I think(?)). Ex. if function currently depends on something in an unnamed namespace which is also used by other functions in the current same source file.

Comment: I agree with what others have said. But if you're _really really_ determined... you could use CMake to make a modified version of the source file where you insert the C++ attribute. See [How can I replace string in a source file before compilation using CMake?](/q/75761012/11107541)